# Angular Upgrade to 13 added a lot of angular cache

Tags: angular, webpack, angular13

I had upgraded to angular 13 recently and found a lot of cache files called .angular\cache\13.3.10

This has two sub folders
angular-webpack
babel-webpack

[image: angular-webpack]
[image: Babel-webpack]

So upgraded from 12.2.17 to 13.3.12 manually and app is up and running.
what can be done with this cache file.please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache files are used to decrease the time taken to build the application. It restores and reuses the previously performed operations. It is used for local environment.

If we delete this folder, angular will recreate it while building.

You can refer [here](https://angular.io/cli/cache) for more information.